# Where can I see/photograph the KT boundary on South Table Mountain?

Tags: mass-extinction

The KT boundary was first discovered in North America at South Table Mountain near Golden, Colorado in 1943.  Supposedly, it is a dark layer 1-3 cm deep sandwiched between lighter clay.

I would like to go hiking there and see the deposited boundary and take some photographs.  Could someone give me gps coordinates of where exactly the boundary is in the park?

Comment: Please post an answer if you end up going!

Comment: yes, I will do that

Answer (score 2):

According to [Cretaceous-Paleogene Boundary](https://epod.usra.edu/blog/2013/10/cretaceous-paleogene-boundary.html) the coordinates are: [39.7488 deg N, -105.1633 deg E](https://www.google.com/maps/place/39%C2%B044%2755.7%22N+105%C2%B009%2747.9%22W/@39.7481428,-105.1769281,4304m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x3e7625a8c4a8415f!8m2!3d39.7488!4d-105.1633)

The linked page has some photographs with this descriptive text:

> The Cretaceous-Paleogene (K-Pg) boundary, formerly known as the
> Cretaceous-Tertiary (K-T) boundary, was first described in terrestrial
> (non-marine) rocks at the above site on South Table Mountain in
> Golden, Colorado back in 1943. This boundary actually isn't visually
> well-defined here but was recognized on the basis of fossil evidence
> long before the more recently applied evidence of the boundary was
> imagined. It occurs somewhere within the eroded slope of the badlands
> topography in the lower-right portion of the photograph. This site was
> judged to be so important to the history of science that the National
> Science Foundation held its 50th birthday party here in 2000. Note the
> tall buildings of downtown Denver in the distance, about 9 mi (14 km)
> directly to the east. Photo taken on January 30, 2011.

Comment: Looks legit. From [this photo](https://www.worldwidepanorama.org/wwp609/ShawnSteigner-5583.html) I think it looks like you want the gully about 50 SSW of that marker.